# Android Studio App crashes when clicking on MenuIcons

Tags: android

My `App` crashes when I'm clicking on a `Button`.
I'm using `Java` with `AndroidX`.

Code for the Button:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/addreminder"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_addreminder"
    android:title="@string/label_addreminder"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Code for the Toolbar in MainActivity:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuicons, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addreminder:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Add Reminder Option selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent openAddReminderButton = new Intent(this, AddReminder.class);
            startActivity(openAddReminderButton);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
 }
```

Code for Activity which should open:

```
    package com.vrobinde.reminder;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

        import android.os.Bundle;

public class AddReminder extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_reminder);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarmainmenu);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

Formatting is bad here, in Android Studio it looks fine.

Stacktrace:
https://hastebin.com/wucojuhalo.coffeescript

Comment: please put crash log

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're calling `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` before `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`. So change your `AddReminder` code as:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_reminder);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarmainmenu);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // only after setting toolbar as support action bar.
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

If this still doesn't solve your problem please update the question with the stack trace.

Comment: Have you changed font in any of the components ?

Comment: the crash is happening there try removing it and try debugging with above changes and see if it still crashes.

Comment: Still crashing :/